# Can I get parent class name ( first one) on inherit classes?

Tags: oop, inheritance, haxe

At example I have three classes : View , FView ( extends View) and MView (extends View) . I have variable from type MView and want to to check it against parent class View ( i.e if this variable is from class View ). Is it possible to get the parent class ( View class) ?  . Here is full example: https://try.haxe.org/#eA594

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var v = new SView();
        trace(Type.getClassName( Type.getSuperClass(Type.getClass(v))) );
    }
}
```

class View :

```
class View {
    public function new() {

    }
}
```

class FView :

```
class FView  extends View { 
    public function new() {
        super();
    }
}
```

class SView :

```
class SView  extends FView {
    public function new() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention `MView` but your current example doesn't include it.  Instead it includes `SView` which inherits `FView`, so the class hierarchy listed above is different than you describe.  What is the correct class hierarchy? It seems like your code example above is working correctly, currently.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get to the base class, you can simply recurse or iterate until `Type.getSuperClass()` returns `null`:

```
// at runtime: find out what is the base class of `v`
var base:Class<Dynamic> = Type.getClass(v);
while (true) {
    var s = Type.getSuperClass(base);
    if (s == null)
        break;
    base = s;
}
trace(Type.getClassName(base));
```

However, you mention that you want to do this simply to check if `MView` (or `SView`) are of the `View` type.

Well, for this, there are a few simpler alternatives...

First, at compile type, you can simply use a [type check](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-type-check.html) (or an assignment) to check if `v:SView` [unifies](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-unification.html) with `View`:

```
// at compile time: enforce that `v` be of type `View` or compatible with it
var v1 = (v:View);  // use a type check
var v2:View = v;    // or simply pass it to something expecting `View`
```

If you need to do it at runtime, that's possible as well with `Std.is()`:

```
// at runtime: check if `v` is a subclass instance of `View`
trace(Std.is(v, View));
```

For a complete example, check out [this](https://try.haxe.org/#fD91F) Try Haxe instance.